# How to obtain gems compatibility version from Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ruby gems are installed into directories called after the last compatible version rather than specific release. How can I obtain that version?

For example for Ruby `2.3.3`, gems will be installed into `2.3.0` directory. How do I find out what that version is from a ruby interpreter?

Comment: aren't they installed into the ruby version you're using at the time you install them?

Comment: @maxple yes, but that's not the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers that are kind of correct, but use paths. I tracked it down to:

```
Gem.ruby_api_version
```

Which will return the version on its own.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gem.loaded_specs
```

will give you a hash of loaded gems. From that list, choose one gem:

```
Gem.loaded_specs["did_you_mean"]
# => {"did_you_mean"=>#<Gem::Specification:0x2abac1f4ecb8 did_you_mean-1.0.0>}
```

`gem_dir` will give you the directory:

```
Gem.loaded_specs["did_you_mean"].gem_dir
# => ".../.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.0.0"
```

In this case, I am using Ruby 2.3.3, and the gems are under the 2.3.0 directory.

Answer (score 0):

i get that same behavior with 2.3.1. here's one way of coming up with "2.3.0":

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin16]

% ruby -e 'print Gem.user_dir'
/Users/kburnett/.gem/ruby/2.3.0

% ruby -e "print RbConfig::CONFIG['ruby_version']"
2.3.0
```